# Why can't I destroy my StaticText in wxPython?

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython, tuples

I am trying to delete statictext from a list and I get the error: `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'Destroy'`.  I can't seem to find a way around it.  My code:

```
import wx
class oranges(wx.Frame):



    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,'Testing',size=(300,300))
        self.frame=wx.Panel(self)
        subtract=wx.Button(self.frame,label='-',pos=(80,200),size=(30,30))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.sub,subtract)
        self.trying=[]
        self.something=0
    def sub(self,event):
        for i in zip(self.trying):
            i.Destroy()
        self.something += 1
        self.trying.append(wx.StaticText(self.frame,-1,str(self.something),pos=(200,200)))
        self.trying.append(wx.StaticText(self.frame,-1,str(self.something),pos=(250,200)))


if __name__ =='__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    window = oranges(parent=None,id=-1)
    window.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

I am really confused on why the StaticText is in a tuple.  Thanks so much in advance!  Looking forward to the answers!

Comment: Did you read the documentation for the [zip function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) you use there in your code?

Comment: No, I realize that doesn't work now. Is there something else I could use?

Comment: I am not sure i understand your last comment. Why do you think you need to substitute zip() with something else instead of letting the for-loop simply iterate over the *self.trying* list? (Also, after destroying the StaticText objects, you want/need to remove them from the *self.trying* list...)

Comment: In your own words, why are you using `zip` there in the first place? What is it supposed to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need only `for i in self.trying:`.

But if you destroy `StringText` you have to remove it from list `self.trying` too.

```
def sub(self,event):

    for i in self.trying:
        i.Destroy()
    self.trying = [] # remove all StaticText from list

    self.something += 1
    self.trying.append(wx.StaticText(self.frame,-1,str(self.something),pos=(200,200)))
    self.trying.append(wx.StaticText(self.frame,-1,str(self.something),pos=(250,200)))
```

---

Do you have to destroy and create again `StaticText` ?
Can't you change text in `StaticText` using `SetLabel` ?

```
import wx
class oranges(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,'Testing',size=(300,300))
        self.frame=wx.Panel(self)
        subtract=wx.Button(self.frame,label='-',pos=(80,200),size=(30,30))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.sub,subtract)

        self.trying=[]
        self.trying.append(wx.StaticText(self.frame,-1,'',pos=(200,200)))
        self.trying.append(wx.StaticText(self.frame,-1,'',pos=(250,200)))

        self.something=0

    def sub(self,event):
        self.something += 1
        for i in self.trying:
            i.SetLabel(str(self.something))            

if __name__ =='__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    window = oranges(parent=None,id=-1)
    window.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```